# Javascript - How to replace a certain occurence of a anchor's href contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a widget (Purechat) that allows customers and operators to communicate to each other. I've ran into an issue where anchors' href values inside this widget are being appended with "http://%20", thus making them unclickable to our users. We are investigating the code, however, I would like a quick fix for this by replacing all href contents that contain "http://%20" and replace that portion of the href with an empty string so my anchors work.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: That's an empty space percent encoded after `http://`

Comment: I'm aware of that. However, I'm just not too sure what is causing this and I need to replace it as soon as it happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').attr('href', function(index, value) { 
  return value.replace("//%20", ""); 
});
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working, does this run initially or is it constantly running? I need this to update asynchronously as it is in a chat widget so URLS may or may not be present all the time, but if they are and they match the href then it should modify it in real-time.

Comment: In that case this should be run every time a new message in the chat is retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a foreach jquery function which runs over every anchor whose href starts with that string, then cut it with substring method and set it's href value again.

This should work:

```
$("a[href^='http://%20']").each(function(){
  var oldHref = $(this).attr('href');
  var newHref = oldHref.substring(10, oldHref.length);
  $(this).attr('href',newHref);
});
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working, does this run initially or is it constantly running? I need this to update asynchronously as it is in a chat widget so URLS may or may not be present all the time, but if they are and they match the href then it should modify it in real-time.

Comment: This piece of code should be run whenever you want to make the replacement.